# Cannot get Ubuntu 22.04 to connect Canon Pixma G3501 printer

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

The printer worked well with Ubuntu 21.10 but the same settings do not work with Ubuntu 22.04.
I have tried to compile the Canon driver for Linux 64bit but the make command gives the following error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcnbpcnclapicom2: No such file or directory".
Can anyone help?

Comment: Give the output of `driverless`, please.

Comment: There is no output from driverless but I do not know if I asked in the right directory